# Is my free working correctly?

Tags: c, free

I wrote up this code to see what would happen after i free up some memory after it has been allocated but I can't understand what is happening here.

The program asks the user for 3 inputs (via keyboard). It then prints out each input entered and where in memory they are stored. The program then 'frees' the allocated memory and reprints out the new content from the same memory addresses.

The way I understand it is that once the memory has been 'freed', the previous content stored in there will be deleted and instead be replaced by some random number. This happens in the first two addresses of ptr, but for some reason the third number I entered is always still stored in '&ptr[2]' even after I free(ptr). What is happening here? Why is it not reverting back to a random number as it was before the malloc() was used?

Also i wanted to ask, after the malloc part, is (ptr) exactly the same as (&ptr[0]) ??

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

main ()
{
    int *ptr;
    int req = 3;
    int i;

    ptr = malloc (req * sizeof(*ptr));

    for (i=0; i<req ; i++)
    {
        printf("Please enter a number: ");
        fflush(stdin);
        scanf("%d", &ptr[i]);
    }

    for (i=0; i<req; i++)
    {
        printf("Number #%d is %d and stored in memory address %d\n", (i+1), ptr[i], &ptr[i]);
    }

    free(ptr);

    for (i=0; i<req; i++)
    {
        printf("Number #%d is %d and stored in memory address %d\n", (i+1), ptr[i], &ptr[i]);
    }

}
```

Comment: Your understanding is incorrect. There's no requirement to replace the freed memory with random numbers.

Comment: Freeing memory just makes it available to be used for future `malloc` calls. Nothing else is done to it.

Comment: Curious: How did you get the idea that `fflush(stdin);` is a good thing to do?

Comment: I have been using `fflush(stdin)` after (or before) all my calls to `scanf`, so that even if you enter multiple numbers at once (e.g "10 20 22 33") only the first number (in this case "10") will be read and the rest will be cleared. If i didn't use it, all 3 elements of ptr could be set with one keyboard input which I didn't like.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The way I understand it is that once the memory has been 'freed', the
>   previous content stored in there will be deleted and instead be
>   replaced by some random number.

No thats not true. Once you free the memory it is available and you can use it for any future allocation of memory. There is nothing like that the memory is replaced with random numbers once the memory is freed. This is completely wrong.

Comment: Oh ok. So then, why is it that the content stored in the first two addresses gets overwritten with other numbers if free was not suppose to do anything other than make the memory available?

Comment: When you do free, the memory can be reused. For example, another malloc could use it (not the case here, given your code). Also, free COULD write information at the start of the chunk depending on implementation - for example, an instrumented version could write information about the calling file and line number to assist with debugging of multiple frees for the same chunk of memory. Or it might link the freed memory into the free list which could end up using the start of the previously allocated memory.

Answer (score 0):

As the previous posters said, the memory is NOT overwritten by random once you free it.
If you really want that, the PaX Patchset for the Linux Kernel has CONFIG_PAX_MEMORY_SANITIZE which does exactly that.

Answer (score 0):

Once a `malloc()`'ed pointer is freed, dereferencing that pointer again is undefined behavior.

The value returned may be the same or it may be different as before.  The program could seg fault.  Many possibilities.  The behavior is undefined.